# jQuery, duplicate selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code warning me the duplicate `$("#demo-select")` use of the selector:

```
    let demoSelect = $("#demo-select").val();
        if (demoSelect){

            $('#days_count').show();
        }

        $("#demo-select").change(function(){
            if (this.value){
                $('#days_count').show();
            } else {
                $('#days_count').hide();
            }

        });
```

How could I write that code in order to not duplicate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is from the repeated use of `$('#demo-select')`. You can create a variable which holds that value and re-use that. This is preferred because DOM access is a (relatively) slow operation and should be avoided where possible.

```js
let $demoSelect = $("#demo-select").change(function() {
  if (this.value) {
    $('#days_count').show();
  } else {
    $('#days_count').hide();
  }
});

if ($demoSelect.val()) {
  $('#days_count').show();
}
```

*However*, you can avoid the problem and make your logic far more succinct by using `toggle()` and triggering a `change` event on load, like this:

```js
$("#demo-select").change(function() {
  $('#days_count').toggle(!!this.value);
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a warning because it's quite expensive to query a selector in the DOM.

So you should cache a copy of the jQuery object and then reference it when needed.

```
let $demoSelect = $("#demo-select");
let demoSelectVal = $demoSelect.val();

if (demoSelectVal){
  $('#days_count').show();
}

$demoSelect.change(function(){
  if (this.value){
    $('#days_count').show();
  } else {
    $('#days_count').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely a warning by your IDE or some linting tool.

You are capturing the element in `let demoSelect = ("#demo-select");`, but then re-select the element via `$("#demo-select").change...`, you should just reuse `demoSelect`:

```
let demoSelect = $("#demo-select");

if (demoSelect.val()) {
    $('#days_count').show();
}

demoSelect.change(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        $('#days_count').show();
    } else {
        $('#days_count').hide();
    }
});
```

Notice that the check for `.val()` is now in the if statement.